# Confusion surrounding etymology of 'Burdock'

Tags: etymology

*Arctium lappa*; Common Name: Burdock.

Is it simply a coincidence that 'Arctium,' meaning 'Bear,' the animal, sounds like 'Bur' in 'Burdock?' (viz., NOT bear-dock, but bur-dock).
The etymology does not seem to link them.

What I can see:
'Bear' comes from brown.
'Bur' comes from bristle.

The jump to Arctium is simply a coincidence that the bear happens to bristle, and so looks like the small bur.

From *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/burdock)*:

> common name of a kind of coarse, weedy plant, 1590s, from bur + dock (n.3).
>
> **bur (n.):** "prickly seed vessel of some plants," c. 1300, burre, from a Scandinavian source (compare Danish borre, Swedish hard-borre, Old Norse burst "bristle"), from PIE *bhars- (see bristle (n.)). Transferred 1610s to "rough edge on metal," which might be the source of the sense "rough sound of the letter -r-" (see burr). Also the name given to various tools and appliances.

From *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bear)*:

> **bear (n.):** "large carnivorous or omnivorous mammal of the family Ursidae," Old English bera "a bear," from Proto-Germanic *bero, literally "the brown (one)" (source also of Old Norse björn, Middle Dutch bere, Dutch beer, Old High German bero, German Bär), usually said to be from PIE root *bher- (2) "bright; brown." There was perhaps a PIE *bheros "dark animal" (compare beaver (n.1) and Greek phrynos "toad," literally "the brown animal").

From *[Botanical](https://botanical.com/botanical/mgmh/b/burdoc87.html)*:

> The name of the genus, Arctium, is derived from the Greek arktos, a bear, in allusion to the roughness of the burs ...

> The plant gets its name of 'Dock' from its large leaves; the 'Bur' is supposed to be a contraction of the French bourre, from the Latin burra, a lock of wool, such is often found entangled with it when sheep have passed by the growing plants.

Comment: The full OED says the initial syllable of ***burdock*** (a particular type of ***dock***) is just the word ***bur, burr*** - defined by them as *Any rough or prickly seed-vessel or flower-head of a plant* (origin: *identical or cognate with Danish **borre bur**, "burdock", Swedish **borre** "sea-urchin"*.  No mention of ***bears*** or tangled wool there.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Isn't Arctium from the Latin *arction* meaning "unknown plant?" I thought *-ium* indicated a borrowing from Latin.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it simply a coincidence that 'Arctium,' meaning 'Bear,' the animal, sounds like 'Bur' in 'Burdock?' (viz., NOT bear-dock, but bur-dock).

Yes. Sound similarity is not a useful tool to figure out etymological connections between words. *Bear* and *burdock* are not cognates in English.

For instance, all of these words differ from *bear* in one vowel sound, but are otherwise unrelated etymologically to *bear*:

*beer*
*bore*
*bur*
*bar*
*birr*
*byre*
*ber*

Even the verb *bear*, meaning *carry*, is unrelated etymologically to the animal *bear*. The OED eventually traces the verb *[bear](https://oed.com/view/Entry/16543)* to:

> the same Indo-European base as Sanskrit bhṛ-, ancient Greek ϕέρειν, classical Latin ferre, Early Irish beirid (3rd singular indicative), Armenian berem (1st singular indicative), Albanian bie (imperative singular bjer), all in the senses ‘to carry, to bring’, and also (with secondary senses) Welsh †beru to flow, Old Church Slavonic bĭrati to gather, Lithuanian berti to scatter.

So sound is insufficient to connect the etymology of two words. So is meaning.

Even if you could find a small bit of similar meaning between the words, that isn't sufficient for showing that the two words are cognates. For instance. *island* and *isle* look similar in form and mean similar things, but have completely different etymologies: *island* comes from Old English *ig-land*, and *isle* comes from the Latin *insula*. Word pairs like this are called [false cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate), and they're textbook examples of how two similar words can form coincidentally without sharing a common root.

So if the dictionary is telling you that the two words are not related, you're going to need better evidence than sound or meaning similarity to show that they're related.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it simply a coincidence that 'Arctium,' meaning 'Bear,' the animal, sounds like 'Bur' in 'Burdock?'

Yes.